# Кнопка-картинка

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qpushbutton

Я делаю приложение в *Qt Designer* и мне надо так, чтобы иконка в кнопке закрывала ее полностью.

Вот что у меня получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мне надо так, чтобы иконка была размером в кнопку.

Comment: вам надо подсказать, как увеличить элементы (изображения) в qt designer-е?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**q1279503.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>264</width>
    <height>209</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="icon">
       <iconset>
        <normalon>cat.jpg</normalon>
       </iconset>
      </property>
      <property name="iconSize">
       <size>
        <width>90</width>
        <height>70</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**q1279503_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(264, 209)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("cat.jpg"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.On)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(90, 70))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]